# PHP gets all the keys of memcached always return false

Tags: php, memcached

I want to get the name of all keys for memcached, but Memcached::getAllKeys method always return false.
use contos 6.5 + memcached 1.4.31 + php-memcached-2.2.0 PECL

Comment: https://github.com/bainternet/Memchaced-Dashboard looks helpful

Answer (score 1):

It looks like newer versions of memcached don't like nor support the getAllKeys method.

However it looks like someone made it work by setting

```
Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL = false
```

If it does not work I think you have to fall back to 1.4.23 version or install REDIS :P

Comment: I have tried this Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL = false, not work.  maybe I need to use 1.4.23. I'll try it first @Borjante Thank

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my live server. I was preparing a test to show the techs there how to replicate my problem:

```
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer(MEMCACHED_SERVER, MEMCACHED_PORT);

echo "added ". MEMCACHED_SERVER. ":". MEMCACHED_PORT. PHP_EOL;

$keys = [];
$stop = 100;
foreach( $m->getAllKeys() as $k){
    array_push( $keys, $k );
    if( --$stop == 0 ) break;
}

var_dump( $keys );
```

this would return 100 keys on my local R&D server, but an empty list on the live server. To show them there was definitely something in there I echoed a dump of a key in there that I knew for sure was there:

```
var_dump( $m->get( "cache:pool:70:230" ));
```

that line showed there was a key, but it also made getAllKeys to return a list of 100 entries more! I still believe this is a bug, but there is a workaround.

Edit: Turns out any redundant call before getallkeys fixes this: $m->getVersion(); would also make getAllKeys works